# How do I find out if visible elements with a certain class name are empty or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

At first I was doing this, but then I realized this can't work because not all the elements will be visible. I don't mean hidden, I mean it won't even show up in the DOM. This whole chunk of code (minus the document.ready part) is done 6 times for 6 fields that have 6 different names, so when either of the 6 are typed into it checks the other 5.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.body).on("input", "input[name='count1']", function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            var count1val = $("#count1").val();
            var count2val = $("#count2").val();
            var count3val = $("#count3").val();
            var count4val = $("#count4").val();
            var count5val = $("#count5").val();
            var count6val = $("#count6").val();
            if (count1val !== '' && count2val !== '' && count3val !== '' && count4val !== '' && count5val !== '' && count6val !== '') {
                //do something
            }
        }
    });
});
```

So then I needed to see if all inputs that are visible with a certain class name are empty. Needs to be with class name because there will be multiple sets I need to handle the same way and I don't want one set to interfere with other sets. I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.body).on("input", "input[name='count1']", function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            if ($(".countmulti:visible").val() !== '') {
                //do something
            }
        }
    });
});
```

What is a better way to find out if all of a set of visible fields with a specific class name are empty or not.

To explain better about the visible fields; sometimes it will be only field 1 visible, sometimes field 1 and 2, sometimes 1, 2, and 3, sometimes 1, 2, 3, and 4, sometimes 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, and sometimes all 6.

i solved it with another Q&A on stackoverflow.  here is what i used:

```
var inputsWithNoValue = $(".countmulti:visible").filter(function() {
    return !this.value.length;
});
if (inputsWithNoValue.length) { // if there are inputs with no value
    alert('something empty');
} else {
    alert('nothing empty');
}
```

Comment: how many .countmulti classes do you have? are you 100% sure it is only one class like this?

Comment: 6 inputs have same class name.

Comment: @leoarce You should make your edit an [answer to your question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var inputsWithNoValue = $(".countmulti:visible").filter(function() {
    return !this.value.length;
});
if (inputsWithNoValue.length) { // if there are inputs with no value
    alert('something empty');
} else {
    alert('nothing empty');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `console.log($(".countmulti:visible"))`? It may be an array.
It is possible that it returns many elements, so you would have to use **each** to iterate over array.

The answer is iterating over it.
Instead of:

```
  if ($(".countmulti:visible").val() !== '') {
        //do something
    }
```

Write

```
var res = $(".countmulti:visible");
$.each(res, function( index, value ) {
  if ( res[index].val() !== '' ) //do something
});
```

The problem is, that given selector returns many objects instead of one, what was before.

Comment: tried it, but it didn't work. my alert test never popped up. $.each($(".countmulti:visible"), function( index, value ) {if ( value.val() !== '' ) {alert('ok');}});

Comment: can you console.log $(".countmulti:visible")?

Comment: never used console.log. don't know how to implement it. i stuck it in there and it did nothing.

Comment: ok i have to use it with console debug tool. bunch of things popped up. long list of objects then this error: TypeError: res[index].val is not a function if ( res[index].val() !== '' ) { (it's pointing at "res")

Comment: What's the difference between property value and attribute value? All the property values are filling up with what is typed in the input boxes and all the attribute values are staying empty.

Comment: Object[input#count1.countmulti.span12 property value = "a" attribute value = "", input#count2.countmulti.span12 attribute value = "", input#count3.countmulti.span12 attribute value = "", input#count4.countmulti.span12 attribute value = "", input#count5.countmulti.span12 attribute value = "", input#count6.countmulti.span12 attribute value = ""]

Comment: i changed that line to this - if ( $(res[index]).val() !== '' ) - and it works better, but it alerts every time for every field. i just need it to alert if all of the visible fields have a value in them.